# how to make the histogram fill option work

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to see the distribution difference between two groups in my data.
My data looks similar to

```
data <- data.frame(rnorm(500,mean = 3),sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=500))
colnames(data) <- c('x','y')
```

And then I draw the histogram by

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, fill = y)) +
   geom_histogram(alpha=0.6, bins = 50, position = 'identity')
```

But it returns

[image]

Can you please help find what the problem is? I just followed the examples from googling.
Thank you!

Comment: Try with converting to a factor, i.e. `fill = factor(y)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want y as discrete groups, you should convert it to a factor

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = x, fill = factor(y))) +
  geom_histogram(alpha=0.6, bins = 50, position = 'identity')
```

[image]